# pdf/a-1 to any raster image format

Tags: file-conversion, pdfa

I'm looking for a very simple C or C++ open source converter from pdf/a-1 to any image format. I've seen something like mupdf but more than 200 source files are too many for my application. Pdf/a-1 is a subset of pdf so my hope is to find something simpler than a generic pdf converter like mupdf. I don't need to display on screen. Any suggestion apperciated,
BR Tommaso

Answer (score 0):

PDF is a complicated format, even with the PDF/A-1 subset. I doubt you can find anything smaller than MuPDF.